# How to add Line Break dynamically in crystal report formula

Tags: crystal-reports, report

I have a formula field in my crystal report which is set as "Html Text" in text interpretation. I want to add Line Break So I simply use this

```
"<br>"&{MyField}
```

But I want to add Line break dynamically such as it should be aligned according to my field value. For example, if field value is 2 then there will be 2 line breaks or if value is 5 then line breaks will be 5 like this.....

```
if {LineBreak} = 5 then
"<br><br><br><br><br>"&{MyField}

if {LineBreak} =2 then
"<br><br>"&{MyField}
```

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use a loop to add `<br>`s; something like:

```
Local NumberVar i;
Local StringVar lineBreaks;

lineBreaks := "";
for i := 1 to {LineBreak} do (
    lineBreaks := "<br>" & lineBreaks;
    );

lineBreaks & {MyField};
```

Answer (score 1):

instead of `HTML` you can directly use `Chrw(13)` in normal formula field.

try below code:

```
Local Numbervar i;
Local Numbervar j;
Local Stringvar break;
Local Stringvar break1;

for i:=1 to count(databasefield) do
(
break1:="";
for j:=1 to i do
(
if databasefield=i
then break:=break+chrw(13)
);
break1:=break1+break+databasefield;
);

break1;
```

Comment: Hi @Siva,  Thanks for your answer, but It's necessary to use HTML because I have to show HTML Contents. So I can't Use Chrw(13)

Comment: you can use the logic... in place of `chrw(13)` use HTML tags and it works